# Why does downsampling leads classification to only predict one class?

Tags: python, class-imbalance

I have a multi-class classification problem. It performs quite well but on the least represented classes it doesn't. Indeed, here is the distribution :

[image]

And here are the classification results of my former classification (I took the numbers off the labels):

[image].

Therefore I tried to improve classificationby downsampling the marjority classes

```
import os
from sklearn.utils import resample

# rebalance data
#df = resample_data(df)

if True:

    count_class_A, count_class_B,count_class_C, count_class_D,count_class_E, count_class_F, count_class_G = df.grade.value_counts()
    count_df = df.shape[0] 
    class_dict = {"A": count_class_A,"B" :count_class_B,"C": count_class_C,"D": count_class_D,"E": count_class_E, "F": count_class_F, "G": count_class_G}
    counts = [count_class_A, count_class_B,count_class_C, count_class_D,count_class_E, count_class_F, count_class_G]
    median = statistics.median(counts)


    for key in class_dict:
        if class_dict[key]>median:
            print(key)
            df[df.grade == key] = df[df.grade == key].sample(int(count_df/7), replace = False) 
                                             #replace=False,    # sample without replacement
                                             #n_samples=int(count_df/7),     # to match minority class
                                             #random_state=123)
# Divide the data set into training and test sets
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = split_data(df, APPLICANT_NUMERIC + CREDIT_NUMERIC,
                  APPLICANT_CATEGORICAL,
                  TARGET,
                  test_size = 0.2,
                  #row_limit = os.environ.get("sample"))
                  row_limit = 552160)
```

However it the results where catastrophic. The model accuracy and the model loss looked to have some issues :

[image]

And everything was classified in "A" on the test set.

Comment: You sure you are really down sampling the data? Does `df` shape changes? This line  `df[df.grade == key] = df[df.grade == key].sample(int(count_df/7), replace = False)` seems weird to me.

Comment: I'm not sure anymore. I also tried with `df.loc[df.grade == key] = df.loc[df.grade == key].sample(`. How would you have done it ?

Answer (score 0):

For the looks of it the sampling method you used isnt doing the trick.
The way you use pandas slicing and assignment is a bit off.

Something like this might work:

```
dfs = []
for key in class_dict:

    if class_dict[key] > median:
        factor = int(count_df/7)
        key_df = df[df.grade == key].sample(factor, replace=False)
    else:
        key_df = df[df.grade == key]

    dfs.append(key_df)
new_train_df = pd.concat(dfs, sort=False)
```

While this might work, there are more straight forward ways down sampling the data(like setting the exact number of samples expected from each class).
This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52735334/python-pandas-resample-dataset-to-have-balanced-classes) has nice answers too.

Answer (score 0):

You are implementing downsampling from scratch. There may be bugs in your implementation.

Another option is using an established package for down sampling, such as [imblearn's under_sampling](https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/references/under_sampling.html#module-imblearn.under_sampling).